# How to get telnet to send text and keep connected?

Tags: bash, telnet

for my work I need to connect to a lot of different servers every day: telnet ti the host, enter username, enter password - commence work.
Now I wanted to make life easier by automatically entering the username - I managed to do that, but telnet quits afterwards, that's obviously not what I wanted.

I work from a system with BASH and I can't install any programs there, so **please don't give answers like "Use expect, that solves your problem easily..."**

My tries led me to this:

```
function tn() { (echo "user"
                sleep 1) | telnet $1 23
        }
```

Calling the function with *tn 123.45.67.89* connects to the server at 123.45.67.89, where the username is asked, which is entered automatically - great!
But then the password is asked, and instead of letting me enter it and begin my work, the connection is closed.

I really hope someone knows a solution for this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an `Expect` script that ends with the `interact` command.

Comment: Respecting your request to not recommend other tools, can you help us understand why you're using telnet instead of SSH?

Comment: Some servers require SSH, some have it blocked. It's not my decision what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `expect` command to script interactions with telnet:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function tn() {

  expect -f <<EOF
spawn telnet $1
expect "login"
send "${2}\r"
interact 
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but since I'm not an admin I can't use anything like _expect_ - just commands that are provided with bash.

Answer (score 0):

`telnet`is designed for interactive usage. Use `netcat`, `ncat`, `nc`, `socat` or any other tool of this family.

Example:

```
( echo "user"; sleep 1) | ncat $1 23
```

But if you want to simulate interactive behavior, use `socat` and redirect stdin+stdout to a script:

Example:

```
socat TCP:$1:23 EXEC:my-shell.sh
```

In this case, a TCP connection for address $1 port 23 is established and stdin+stdout are redirected to stdout+stdin of the script. See `man socat` for details and more options.

my-shell.sh look for example like:

```
#!/bin/sh

read line
do_domething "$line"
printf "reply\n"

read line
do_domething "$line"
printf "reply\n"
```

btw, I have tested nothing (just written down)